# svn log first 10 only

Tags: svn

how do I get the first 10 entries on svn log for a file
svn log myfile.php

thanks

Comment: You've accepted an "answer" that doesn't actually answer your question. I suggest you fix that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html):

`svn log -l10 myfile.php`

Comment: This actually gets the last 10 changes. If you want the first 10, use Anti Veeranna's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

If you want *first* 10 logs, then

> svn log -r 0:HEAD  -l 10 myfile.php

Answer (score 4):

The command is the following:

```
svn log -l 10 filename
```